# Cannot connect with latest Edge browser to Windows Server 2012 R2 web server

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-edge

I have two Windows Server 2012 R2 servers, one with IIS, the other with Apache2. They are used as internal web servers, and they have auto-generated, untrusted certificates.

Using Edge browser version 121.0.2277.112, attempting to connect to these web servers using HTTPS returns:  **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** which seems to be related to a TLS mismatch.

Firefox complains about the certificates, we are able to accept the risk and continue. What can I try to solve the problem ?

**Update 1**

I installed IIS on another server with the same OS and I can connect to it using Edge. Don't know the details of the TLS protocol but I notices that the *client hello* is slightly different in this successful case.I suppose it depends on something the server has already said to the client, but I don't know what and where to check.

**Update 2**

I erroneously wrote the problem was common to 2 windows server. I checked better and it is limited to one of them with WSUS and Trend Micro antivirus server. I summarize what happens: it works well using Firefox, connecting is immediately drop server side using Edge. The server event log is full of errors like this one: *An error occurred while using SSL configuration for endpoint 0.0.0.0:443.  The error status code is contained within the returned data.*
**Client hello** using Firefox or Edge toward other servers is slightly different to the one from Edge to the problematic server, but it is the first message, I cannot understand the source of this difference.

Comment: Upgrade the servers to use modern TLS ciphers.

Comment: Using Firefox the server hello response shows Cipher suite **TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA**. It is one of the ciphers proposed by Edge too, so I'm very confused. The major difference I can see is that Firefox says it supports TLS >=1.0, while Edge asks for >=1.2

Comment: Firefox follows web standards, RFC and policies very strictly, where with Edge you might get the Microsoft way. If you have Linux terminal available you could also use this script https://github.com/noxxi/p5-ssl-tools/blob/master/analyze-ssl.pl

Answer (score 0):

Use IIS Crypto to enable the proper cipher suites
https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto

It looks like these cipher suites are supported
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-8-1

But require this update:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-rt-8-1-windows-8-1-and-windows-server-2012-r2-update-april-2014-3c9d820b-7079-359d-8660-21de648fa31d

Comment: The update KB2919355 is installed in the server. According to some documents in internet I should find the installed ciphers in **HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL** but it is almost empty. I will check the software you suggested.

Comment: Set best practices values with **IIS Crypto**, nothing changed.

Comment: Did you also do a reboot?